# Contractibility of X implies every point is a deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I have a question about whether contractible spaces are path connected or not. I've been solving questions in my textbook, and I've used this many times to the point where I'm not even sure about it anymore.

Let $X$ be contractible. Then $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a one point space $\{*\}$. So there exists functions $f: X \to \{*\}$ and $g:\{*\} \to X$ such that $g\circ f \simeq id_X$.

Let $H: X\times I \to X$ be a homotopy such that $H(X, 0) =g\circ f $ and $H(X, 1) = id_X$. The function $g\circ f$ however is constant, so let $p = (g\circ f)(x)$, $\forall x \in X$. Suppose I had a point $a\in X$.

Is $H(a, t): I\to X$ a path in $X$ from $a$ to $p$? Is it always continuous? I used it to prove that if a space $X$ is contractible, then every point in $X$ is a deformation retract.

---

Let X be homotopy equivalent to the one point space $\{*\}$. Then $\exists$ $f: X \to \{*\}$ and $g:\{*\} \to X$ such that $f\circ g \simeq id_{\{*\}}$ and $g\circ f \simeq id_X$. In particular, let $H$ be the homotopy such that $H(X, 0) = id_X$ and $H(X, 1) = g\circ f = p\in X$.

Let $a \in X$. Define $r: X \to \{*\}$ by $r(x) = a$,  $\forall x \in X$. Let $j: \{*\}\to X$ be the inclusion map. We need to show $j\circ r \simeq id_X$.

$H(a, t)$ is a path in X from $a$ to $p$. Define $F: X\times I \to X$ by 
 $$F(x, t) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    H(x, 2t), & \text{for } t\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    H(a, 2-2t), & \text{for }t \geq \frac{1}{2} 
  \end{cases}
  \right\} $$

Then $F(X, 0) = id_X$ and $F(X, 1) = a=j\circ r$ is a homotopy between the $id_X$ and the retraction $j\circ r$.

---

I would appreciate any critiques.

**Edit**

After insights provided by William in the comments, this proof does not work if we require "Strong Deformation Retraction" or that a set $A\subset X$ be fixed throughout the homotopy for it to be a DR. I don't know if this can be proved to be false, I will leave it open until myself or someone comes up with a proof on why it is false if we require Strong DR.

Comment: You should look at exercise 0.6b in Hatcher, it gives a space which is contractible but which does *not* deformation retract onto any point. I think the issue with your argument is that for a deformation retract the homotopy $H$ would need to fix $p$ for all time, which isn't guaranteed for an arbitrary homotopy.

Comment: As for whether a contractible space is path-connected or not, yes it is, your argument does provide a path from any $a$ to $p$.

Comment: Hmm I'm a little confused after checking out exercise 0.6b. From Munkres, X is contractible $\iff$ X has the homotopy type of a one point set. Then I spotted a question that asked to proof if $X$ is contractible then every point is a deformation retract.

Comment: It's possible Hatcher and Munkres could have different definitions of deformation retraction. In Hatcher, $A\subset X$ is a deformation retraction if there is a homotopy $H\colon X\times I \to X$ such that $H(x, 1)\in A$ for all $x \in X$ and $H(a, t) = a$ for all $a\in A$ and $t\in I$, but other authors only require $H(a, 1) = a$ and call the above a "strong deformation retraction". If Munkres' definition doesn't require $H$ to fix $A$ for all $t$ then I think your argument is valid.

Comment: Munkres' definition does indeed require $H$ to fix $A$ for all $t$. If it's not too much trouble, can you elaborate why the argument fails? I don't see why fixing $p$ throughout the homotopy is required.

Comment: If Munkres' deformation retraction requires $A$ to be fixed for all $t$, and you want to show that $\{p\}$ is a deformation retract of $X$, then you need a homotopy that fixes $p$ for all $t$, by definition. In my version of Munkres, I see that Exercise $8$ for $\S 58$ in Chapter $9$ (on page 366) also asks you to construct a contractible space that doesn't deformation retract onto a point, like the exercise in Hatcher. Can you say where your exercise comes from? Maybe it's just not using the Hatcher/Munkres definition.

Comment: Ahh now I see what you mean. I got the question from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864102/suppose-that-x-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-one-point-space-then-each-point-of?rq=1) and looking at the comments, I guess the statement is false if we require "Strong DR".

Comment: I learned something today. Thanks so much for your time William, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, not every contractible space strongly deformation retracts onto any point, but your argument I think is valid for showing it does weakly deformation retract onto any point. It's unfortunate that there isn't a more consistent terminology between authors. :)